# куда мне вставить этот знак "=" в атрибуте asyns c типом script. Показыает ошибка валидации при проверке rss канала в вебмастере

Tags: javascript

4
371 
Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
Помогите пожалу

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ключевое слово **async** вставляется внутри тега **script**
Можете попробовать разные варианты:

```
<script async src="http://your-script.js"></script>
<script async="" src="http://your-script.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="http://your-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: А куда мне вставить этот код в header?